# Remove index.php from Shared Hosting, Node Application

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm running a node application (Ghost Blog) on my shared hosting service (a2hosting) However I'm having an issue where my Home Page has `/index.php/` at the end. When I navigate to other pages the index.php is not there, and the site works fine, The issue I'm facing is on the following url: http://blog.gregsithole.com

I looked around on stack overflow and found that the issue may be related to my `.htaccess` file and I'm not too familiar with how to set that up, but below is what my.htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:2368/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:2368/$1 [P,L]
```

Please assist as I have been looking around for the past few days, and I haven't found a solution to this problem I'm facing. I've seen various posts on here which are related to CodeIgniter

Comment: A node server does not consider apache style dynamic configuration files. Different http server.

Comment: I believe I'm on an Apache server though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from my hosting service, I finally fixed the issue.

I altered my `.htaccess` file and based on the suggestion, I added the following to it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes 

IndexIgnore * 

DirectoryIndex

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:2368/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:2368/$1 [P,L]
```